# XPath select all child nodes of child-div except for specific class

Tags: php, xpath

I've been trying for a couple of hours and can't get my XPath to select the right text. Here's the structure:

```
<!-- (some divs that don't need to be selected) -->
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="select">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="divwithtext">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="divwithtext">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="divwithtext">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dontselect">
          <div class="divwithtext">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to select all the children of `class="select"` which is a child of `class="main"`, but I don't need the text of `class="dontselect"`.

Note: I am using XPath 1.0 due to php DOMXPath only supporting 1.0.

Edit:

Problem was my PHP code not returning all results that XPath gave me.

Comment: Could you post the XPath queries that you tried and show their results? This might make it easier for people that know about this topic to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I your question to properly format your code - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way :

```
//div[@class='main']//div[@class='select']/div[not(@class='dontselect')]
```

Comment: change tail so : `*[not(@class="dontselect")]` all chilren and you lost the close parenthesis

Comment: Already tried that and for some reason that only selects the first child. and you forgot the ) at the end of not()

Comment: Really strange, if I just leave it like that it will only select the first child. if i add [2] or any other number it will select the child in that position but never more than one.. any ideas?

Comment: In that case, the problem isn't in your xpath, but rather in the code that execute that xpath

Comment: Apparently my PHP was always returning the first result of the object instead of iterating over it and returning everything. @har07 thanks

Comment: @HomelessPerson You need loop with result to receive all data